# Powershell 3 string manipulating using split and join

Tags: string, powershell

I need to capitalize the first letter of each word using split an join using powershell 3.0

I have been going crazy trying to figure this out.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Function Proper( [switch]$AllCaps, [switch]$title, [string]$textentered=" ")
{ 
    if ($AllCaps)
        {$textentered.Toupper()}
    Elseif ($title)
        {$textentered -split " "

        $properwords = $textentered | foreach { $_ }


            $properwords -join " "
            $properwords.substring(0,1).toupper()+$properwords.substring(1).tolower()

            }
}
proper -title "test test"
```

Answer (score 2):

`System.Globalization.TextInfo` class has the `ToTitleCase` method you can use, just join your words as normal into a string (called `$lowerstring` for example) then call the method on that string using the `Get-Culture cmdlet::

```
$titlecasestring = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($lowerstring)
```

For the string concatenation I tend to use the following format:

```
$lowerstring = ("the " + "quick " + "brown " + "fox")
```

But the following are also valid:

```
$lowerstring = 'the','quick','brown','fox' -join " "

$lowerstring = $a,$b,$c,$d -join " "
```

**EDIT:**

Based on the code you supplied, you don't need to split/join strings if what you're passing in is just a phrase in a string, so the following is what you need

```
Function Proper{
    Param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
           [string]$textentered,
           [switch]$AllCaps,
           [switch]$Title)

    if ($AllCaps){$properwords = $textentered.Toupper()} 

    if ($title) {
                 $properwords = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($textentered)
                }

    if ((!($Title)) -and (!($AllCaps))){
        Return $textentered}
} 

Proper "test test" -AllCaps
Proper "test test" -Title
Proper "test test"
```

In the `Param ()` block I set the $textentered parameter as mandatory, and that it must be the first parameter (Position = 0).

If neither of the AllCaps or Title parameters are passed, the original input string is passed back out, unaltered.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is what I came up with. It only capitalizes the first letter of the first word. Function Proper( [switch]$AllCaps, [switch]$title, [string]$textentered=" ")
{ 
 if ($AllCaps)
  {$textentered.Toupper()}
 Elseif ($title)
  {$textentered -split " "

  $properwords = $textentered | foreach { $_ }
  


$properwords -join " "
$properwords.substring(0,1).toupper()+$properwords.substring(1).tolower()


  



}
}
proper -title "test test"